# How to show current week items from power automate flow to sharepoint list in sharepoint home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I've created a Power Automate flow that successfully fetches current week events from a SharePoint list. The flow outputs this data correctly. However, I'm struggling to display this list of events dynamically on the SharePoint homepage. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or explanation on how to achieve this?

I've successfully created a Power Automate flow that fetches current week events in JSON format. Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to dynamically display this list of events on the SharePoint homepage. Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated